# How to test OCPP-J v1.6 operations at my charge points?

Tags: ocpp

We have a couple charge points and we need to test the core OCPP operations(version 1.6).
Can anyone tell me where and how I can do it easily and for free?)

I tried to search vai google and all result was complicated and for money(

Answer (score 0):

U can use java app. All u need for this: install IntelliJ IDEA, create simle sping boot+maven app, add dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.extrawest/bdd-charge-point-tester-via-ocpp-j/0.1.2 and create a test file with your demand.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).